# OS won't load after BIOS update (CMOS Settings Wrong)

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

I bought a new PC about 3 months ago. The OS was Ubuntu, so I installed Windows. After that, the audio started to fail. It would work normally until reboot, then it would stop working even with the driver still installed. Then I had to reinstall driver, but it would stop working after every reboot. Trying to solve this, I decided to update BIOS.

This is the computer: centriumpc.com.br/centrium/produto.aspx?codigo=28055

This is the motherboard manufacturer website: http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=1525&CategoryID=1&MenuID=17&OSID=58&DCID=1&LanID=0#fragment-Download

After the update, OS simply won't load, stuck on an American Megratrends screen which says CMOS Settings Wrong. Check it out:

[CMOS Settings Wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWO0p.jpg)

My first attempt was to enter BIOS and set up date and time (they were wrong indeed), but when I tried to "Save and Exit", the screen blinked as if it was about to save changes and then returned to BIOS screen - with no saved settings.

My second attempt was to clear CMOS using the motherboard's jumper, but nothing happened.

My third attempt was to remove battery for a few minutes and it also didn't work.

Could it be any possible that the battery decided to die exactly after the BIOS update? I think it would be such a big coincidence, so I discarded the hypothesis.

Important note: before the update, the initial screen would show a CENTRIUM logo and not an American Megatrends logo.

What I want to know:

1. Did I make a wrong BIOS update even following the link of the motherboard manufacturer?
2. If so, how can I fix this? Is there any way to revert the update if this is what caused the problem?

Please note that:

1. The computer doesn't have an optical driver, so any procedure should involve USB connection.
2. I don't think I killed the motherboard because there is video and the lights of the case turn on and blink as usual.

Any thoughts to help me fix this would be really appreciated.

Thank you,

Giovanna

Comment: Did you use Eblu ( http://www.ecs.com.tw/extra/eblu/ )?

Comment: Hi, Julie. I'm not sure, but I don't think so. Can I re-do the process somehow via USB since the OS won't load?

Comment: Try https://www.bios-mods.com/bios-recovery/ami-bios-recovery/

Comment: Just tried downloading the Global file from [here](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=1525&CategoryID=1&MenuID=17&OSID=58&DCID=1&LanID=0#fragment-Download), followed the instructions and it didn't work. Same screen appears. The system didn't access USB flashdrive.

Comment: Did you try pressing the `Home` key as mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I did. I may be completely wrong since I'm not an expert, but my BIOS chip says ITE not AMIBIOS - [please check this picture I just took](https://s31.postimg.org/lldr2klsr/IMG_5241.jpg), so I'm guessing the file provided by the manufacturer might be wrong. Is there a safe way to recover the correct BIOS?

Comment: Now I'm confused. Just checked a previous report from AIDA64 and it tells me that BIOS is "AMI (05/20/2014)". So, basically, manufacturer and software tell me it's AMI but hardware tells me it's ITE. Who should I believe in?

Comment: That is not the BIOS.

Comment: I doubt the problem would be limited to your hard drive at this point.  Your only option is to find a way to recover your BIOS and it apparently didn't work.  You probably bricked your motherboard.

Comment: I decided to try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmF1lZ-Xnv0), but even when I select the USB flashdrive from the boot menu, it sends me to the BIOS screen. It feels like I can't go anywhere but the BIOS screen. If I bricked the motherboard, what should I do? Buy a new one? Are there any other solutions? Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: I tried to find the BIOS in the picture of your motherboard and couldn't see it.  At first glance I doubt it can be replaced, so replacing the motherboard is probably needed.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, Julie. I'll keep trying to find a solution and I hope someone else can shed some light on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply but this is what I did.

After the bios update go to bios, the boot option would be changed from UEFI to Legacy so just return it to UEFI and try rebooting. should work.